# Make [android-images] a synonym of [android-image]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[android-image](/questions/tagged/android-image) currently does not have a description, and attracts the same questions as [android-images](/questions/tagged/android-images); thus, I suggest that [android-images](/questions/tagged/android-images) be merged into [android-image](/questions/tagged/android-image) (favoring the singular form of the word, to be consistent with the tag synonyms of [image](/questions/tagged/image)).